# Get button value in click inside HTML table

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I create a grid in C# MVC 3. and place a delete button in every rows in the grid.

Please see my image below.

[image]

Delete button code.

```
<td>
 <button id="removefromcart" type="button" name="removefromcart" 
          class="remove-cartitem" value="@(item.Id)"> </button></td>
```

Script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('[name="removefromcart"]').click(function () {
        alert('clicked');
    });

})
```

I try to alert the value of the clicked button.

Please help

Comment: are you getting alert ?

Comment: Yes. with " clicked "... But how to get the value of clicked button ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `class` `attribute` of dom element

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

$('.remove-cartitem').click(function () {
    alert($(this).val());
});

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('.remove-cartitem').click(function () {
    alert($(this).attr('value'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('[name="removefromcart"]').click(function () {
        alert($(this).val());
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your button has an id, i guess it would be better to use this ID to get the element in jquery.

Moreover, the click() function is deprecated, you should use on('click') which allows you to unbind the event with off('click').

```
$('#removefromcart').on('click', function() {
    alert( $(this).val() );
});
```

The best way would be not to use jQuery

```
document.getElementById('removefromcart').addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert( this.attributes.value.nodeValue );
});
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Simply get the value of the DOM element :

```
$('[name="removefromcart"]').click(function () {
    alert(this.value);
});
```

---

EDIT :

`this.value` is equivalent to `$(this).val()` or `$(this).attr('value')` but fastest since we only manipulate DOM attribute (and not a jQuery object)...

See for example : [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/jquery-vs-plain-javascript/3)